# Why can't I update the QTableView model inside a thread automatically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

**Introduction:**

I'm using QT5 and I want to update a `TableView` where my `model` for the `TableView` is updated inside a thread.

**Method*

I create a table like this and set it's columns and rows.

```
/* TableView */
    QStandardItemModel* looping_terminal_model = new QStandardItemModel(4, 2);
    looping_terminal_model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("ID"));
    looping_terminal_model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("DATA"));
    ui->looping_terminal_tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    ui->looping_terminal_tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    ui->looping_terminal_tableView->setModel(looping_terminal_model);
```

Then I starting the thread.

```
    /* Threads */
    this->loop_terminal = new Loop_terminal(j1939, &start_loop_terminal_thread, looping_terminal_model);
    loop_terminal->start();
```

Inside the `loop_terminal` class, it looks like this

```
Loop_terminal::Loop_terminal(J1939* j1939, bool* start_loop_terminal_thread, QStandardItemModel* looping_terminal_model){
    this->j1939 = j1939;
    this->start_loop_terminal_thread = start_loop_terminal_thread;
    this->looping_terminal_model = looping_terminal_model;
    i = 0;
}

void Loop_terminal::run(){
    while(1){
        if(j1939->ID_and_data_is_updated){

            j1939->ID_and_data_is_updated = false;
        }
        QModelIndex index = looping_terminal_model->index(1,1,QModelIndex());
        // 0 for all data
        looping_terminal_model->setData(index,this->i);
        i++;
        msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Result**

The value can be shown in the blue cell. But it only updates if I click on the blue cell.

[image]

**Discussion:**

Here is the problem

```
 looping_terminal_model->setData(index,this->i);
```

Every time I updated an index, I need to press on the blue `TableView` cell, so it can updates. Or else, nothing happens. If I minimize the window, then it updates, but I can't see that.

What should I do, to make sure that the `ui` can update, even if it's outside of the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot and should not. Models are intensively used by the view so they must live (and be modified) in the same thread as the view as they are not thread-safe. The solution is to send the information to the main thread using signals and there just update the model.